# LISP MAKE-PATHNAME: Illegal :DIRECTORY argument

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, clisp, pathname

I download Semantic Network Processor project:
http://digital.cs.usu.edu/~vkulyukin/vkweb/software/snp/snp.html

and following it's read me,
By using CLISP interpreter I change the directory to the folder,
and do the following:

```
[3]> (load "snp-loader.lisp")
;; Loading file snp-loader.lisp ...
;; Loaded file snp-loader.lisp
T

[4]> (in-package "USER")

<PACKAGE COMMON-LISP-USER>

[5]> (snp-load-everything)

**- MAKE-PATHNAME: Illegal :DIRECTORY argument "D:\\snp-stable\\"**

The following restarts are available:
ABORT          :R1      Abort main loop
```

can anybody tells me what's wrong or how I can fix it in order to make the project run?

Comment: FYI, I have the same problem on Linux.

Comment: As a side note clisp is not a great common lisp implementation, please consider sbcl, ccl (which compile to machine-code), ecl (if compiling to c is a requirement) or one of the other standards complaint alternatives

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In *snp-loader.lisp*, instead of `directory-namestring`, you need to call `pathname-directory`:

```
(defparameter parm-snp-load-dir 
  (pathname-directory *load-truename*))
```

But then another problem occurs later, when defining a method for `expectations-on-token`. In *c-snp-with-vars.lisp*, the docstring is malformed, which triggers an error. Join both strings:

```
(defmethod expectations-on-token ((this-snp c-snp-with-vars) (tok t))
  "Overloaded expectations-on-token to process variables and tests.
Get all expectations waiting for the token tok."
  `(,@(find-static-expectations this-snp tok)
       ,@(find-dynamic-expectations this-snp tok)))
```

Reload the *snp-loader.lisp* file, and retry `(snp-load-everything)`. It should load properly.

*Edit. I contacted the original author; the latest version of the code is now hosted on GitHub at https://github.com/VKEDCO/AI/tree/master/NL/SNP*.